# different count from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables as

```
products TABLE
  FIELDS: productid, catid,...

sales TABLE
  FIELDS: trackid, productid,...

promotion TABLE
  FIELDS: trackid, productid,...
```

Now I need something like

```
ProductID     CatID     TotalSales      TotalPromotion
    1           1          10                3
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.productid, 
       a.catid, 
       a.totalsales, 
       b.totalpromotion 
FROM   (SELECT p.productid, 
               p.catid, 
               COUNT(s.productid) AS totalsales 
        FROM   products p 
               LEFT JOIN sales s 
                 ON p.productid = s.productid 
        GROUP  BY p.productid, 
                  p.catid) a 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT p.productid, 
                          p.catid, 
                          COUNT(s.productid) AS totalpromotion 
                   FROM   products p 
                          LEFT JOIN promotion s 
                            ON p.productid = s.productid 
                   GROUP  BY p.productid, 
                             p.catid) b 
         ON a.productid = b.productid
```

Comment: @Cybernate: Its showing 1 for totalsales and totalpromotion for each and everyproduct for whom there is no sales or no promotion

Comment: for those products, were sales is 0 and promotion is 0, it's showing 1, 1

Comment: Are you sure you copied the updated query? I have tested it and it works fine for me.. Pls note the change to COUNT(s.productID)

Answer (score 1):

[Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the above three tables.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help,

> select a.productID, a.catID,
>   b.totalSales, c.Totalpromotion from
>   Product a inner join Sales b on
>   a.catID=b.CatID inner join Promotion c
>   on a.CatID=C.CatID